# Build OpenLDAP client for iOS - no SASL

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, openldap, sasl

Since Apple is systematically deprecating `OpenLDAP` for `iOS` and `OS X` (some features which are needed has been removed in `10.10`), my team decided to get [latest `OpenLDAP`](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=commit;h=2c705e47a38025c99a9b3cebb38b8b09a804c5c5), build it and include libraries to application.

I need only client functionality.

Build for MacOS is not a problem:

```
$ ./configure --with-tls=openssl --disable-slapd \
> --prefix="`pwd`/openldap-build/common" \
> --exec-prefix="`pwd`/openldap-build/MacOS"
$ make depend
$ make
$ make install
```

This goes smoothly.

Problem is building for iOS. I've found nice [solution which allows to build such external libraries for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161949/1387438). I tweak this bash script to go with ~openLDAP` code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PLATFORMPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
TOOLSPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="8.0"
pwd=`pwd`

findLatestSDKVersion()
{
    sdks=`ls $PLATFORMPATH/$1.platform/Developer/SDKs`
    arr=()
    for sdk in $sdks
    do
       arr[${#arr[@]}]=$sdk
    done

    # Last item will be the current SDK, since it is alpha ordered
    count=${#arr[@]}
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
       sdk=${arr[$count-1]:${#1}}
       num=`expr ${#sdk}-4`
       SDKVERSION=${sdk:0:$num}
    else
       SDKVERSION="8.0"
    fi
}

buildit()
{
    target=$1
    hosttarget=$1
    platform=$2

    echo =============================================================
    echo = building for target $target platform $platform ... =
    echo =============================================================

    if [[ $hosttarget == "x86_64" ]]; then
        hostarget="i386"
    elif [[ $hosttarget == "arm64" ]]; then
        hosttarget="arm"
    fi

    export CC="$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang)"
    export CPP="$CC -E"
    export CFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
    export AR=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar)
    export RANLIB=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ranlib)
    export CPPFLAGS="-arch ${target}  -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
    export LDFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk"

    mkdir -p $pwd/output/$target

     ./configure --disable-shared --host=$hosttarget-apple-darwin --with-tls=openssl --disable-slapd --prefix="$pwd/output-build/common"  --exec-prefix="$pwd/output-build/$target"

    make depend
    # make clean
    make
    make install

    echo =============================================================
    echo = Success for target $target platform $platform ... =
    echo =============================================================
}

findLatestSDKVersion iPhoneOS

buildit armv7 iPhoneOS
buildit armv7s iPhoneOS
buildit arm64 iPhoneOS
buildit i386 iPhoneSimulator
buildit x86_64 iPhoneSimulator

#LIPO=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find lipo)
#$LIPO -create $pwd/output/armv7/lib/libpresage.a  $pwd/output/armv7s/lib/libpresage.a $pwd/output/arm64/lib/libpresage.a $pwd/output/x86_64/lib/libpresage.a $pwd/output/i386/lib/libpresage.a -output libpresage.a
```

Configuration and `make depend` are Ok. `make` fails on each iOS target with this error:

```
Making all in /Users/maru/Documents/openldap-2c705e4/libraries
  Entering subdirectory liblutil
cc -g -O2 -I../../include        -I../../include     -arch x86_64  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=8.4  -c -o sasl.o sasl.c
sasl.c:26:10: fatal error: 'sasl/sasl.h' file not found
#include <sasl/sasl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [sasl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-common] Error 1
make: *** [all-common] Error 1
```

Form what I can see `SALS` is not available for iOS and this is source of problems.
How I can overcome this problem? Can I configure `openLDAP` differently so it will use something else? Or is there a decent way to provide `SASL` for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with iOS/OSX, but to disable Cyrus SASL you could try

```
--without-cyrus-sasl
```

in addition to your other `./configure flags`, i.e. you need to run

```
./configure --with-tls=openssl --disable-slapd \
--without-cyrus-sasl \
--prefix="`pwd`/openldap-build/common" \
--exec-prefix="`pwd`/openldap-build/MacOS"
```

For further flags info check out

```
./configure --help
```

and [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/server/openldap.html) nice reference.