# Changing a C library to IOS library getting error

Tags: ios, c, static-libraries, net-snmp

I want to configure a c library to work with Xcode . I am new to this and can’t find much information regards this . First i tried to create a static library to drag and drop all the c files but it didn’t worked because it has dependency . The library i am trying to change to iOS is  [net-snmp](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/download.html) . Further investigation i found we can change a c library to iOS specific using configure , make command . I followed a tutorial and tried to configure using below command in terminal but ended up with an error .

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-utf8 --host=arm-apple-darwin CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk" CXXFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk" LDFLAGS="-L." CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc" CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++"
```

The error is

```
configure: error: You are cross-compiling, but you have not specified the target's endianness
```

Am not sure am in the right track . If anybody done successfully changed a c library to iOS specific .? If yes how to do that .? any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling external C++ library for use with iOS project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016612/compiling-external-c-library-for-use-with-ios-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass another argument to configure script: `--with-endianness=little`. (As far as I remember, iOS runs on little endian platform)

You can get this information by running `./configure --help | grep endian`