# Compiling error in Cocoa Touch Static Library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocoa

The scenario : 
I want to use an external C++ Library in my Swift iOS Project. User OmniProg [very kindly told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886756/xcode-does-not-find-c-static-library) that I need to compile my library with Xcode to compile for the right architecture. Also the Library I am trying to use ([GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de)) relies on another one ([CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/)). I will take care about that later and try to do CLN first. So now I created my new **Project -> Cocoa Touch Static Library** and added all the source into it. After I called the ./configure script in the CLN folder. When I try to compile I get these errors :

[image: Errors]

***What is wrong ?***

Comment: I think the following post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812060/cross-compile-libgcrypt-static-lib-for-use-on-ios.  It has to do with building libgcrypt, but a similar approach should work for building other software that uses `configure`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I found the script in the answer. What does it do ? Do i just need to execute it in the folder of my downloaded library (I think so) ? And what about the relation between my two librarys ? Do I just make a Project for one and one for the other and then include in .a into the other one ?

Comment: Just checked out the link in more detail. Very excited now ! But before i try this - note that the two libraries i am trying to use are related in the point that one needs the other. How do i go about this ? Also what do you suggest, about using the libraries. As you said in your other answer - in a workspace ?