# libxml2 linking error for iOS library

Tags: c++, ios, c, libxml2, spatialite

Make process on a C library causing the linking errors related to architecure.I am trying to build library for iOS but it has got dependancy on libxml2 which in this case I guess is Mac only library

lipo -info confirms the same

admin$lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib
Non-fat file: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib is architecture: x86_64

> ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib, file was
>   built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):
>   /usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_xmlAddChild", referenced from:
>         _setIsoId in libspatialite.a(gg_xml.o)
>   referenced from:
>         _vxpath_eval_expr in libspatialite.a(libsplite_la-virtualxpath.o) ld: symbol(s) not found
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make[4]: *** [demo1] Error 1
>   make[3]:**  [install-recursive] Error 1 make[2]:  **[install-strip]
>   Error 2 make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPaXQ.png): ***
>   [/Users/admin/Downloads/libspatialite-ios-master/build/armv7/lib/libspatialite.a]
>   Error 2 make: *** [build_arches] Error 2

**Edit#1**

After commenting, the libspatailite configuration and make section in the make file, I noticed that rest of the dependencies like gets,proj,sqlite are getting generated for all platforms armv7,armv7s,arm64,i386,x86_64.
[image: Snapshot from finder]

lipo -info on these libraries confirm the same.So the problem lies limited to building libspatialite.

Makefile ( To build only libspatialite.a)

```
XCODE_DEVELOPER = $(shell xcode-select --print-path)
IOS_PLATFORM ?= iPhoneOS

# Pick latest SDK in the directory
IOS_PLATFORM_DEVELOPER = ${XCODE_DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${IOS_PLATFORM}.platform/Developer
IOS_SDK = ${IOS_PLATFORM_DEVELOPER}/SDKs/$(shell ls ${IOS_PLATFORM_DEVELOPER}/SDKs | sort -r | head -n1)

all: lib/libspatialite.a
lib/libspatialite.a: build_arches
    mkdir -p lib
    mkdir -p include

    # Copy includes
    cp -R build/armv7/include/geos include
    cp -R build/armv7/include/spatialite include
    cp -R build/armv7/include/*.h include

    # Make fat libraries for all architectures
    for file in build/armv7/lib/*.a; \
        do name=`basename $$file .a`; \
        lipo -create \
            -arch armv7 build/armv7/lib/$$name.a \
            -arch armv7s build/armv7s/lib/$$name.a \
            -arch arm64 build/arm64/lib/$$name.a \
            -arch i386 build/i386/lib/$$name.a \
            -arch x86_64 build/x86_64/lib/$$name.a \
            -output lib/$$name.a \
        ; \
        done;

# Build separate architectures
build_arches:
    ${MAKE} arch ARCH=armv7 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
    ${MAKE} arch ARCH=armv7s IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
    ${MAKE} arch ARCH=arm64 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
    ${MAKE} arch ARCH=i386 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator HOST=i386-apple-darwin
    ${MAKE} arch ARCH=x86_64 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator HOST=x86_64-apple-darwin

PREFIX = ${CURDIR}/build/${ARCH}
LIBDIR = ${PREFIX}/lib
BINDIR = ${PREFIX}/bin
INCLUDEDIR = ${PREFIX}/include

CXX = ${XCODE_DEVELOPER}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
CC = ${XCODE_DEVELOPER}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS = -isysroot ${IOS_SDK} -I${IOS_SDK}/usr/include -arch ${ARCH} -I${INCLUDEDIR} -miphoneos-version-min=7.0
CXXFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -isysroot ${IOS_SDK} -I${IOS_SDK}/usr/include -arch ${ARCH} -I${INCLUDEDIR} -miphoneos-version-min=7.0
LDFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot ${IOS_SDK} -L${LIBDIR} -L${IOS_SDK}/usr/lib -arch ${ARCH} -miphoneos-version-min=7.0

arch: ${LIBDIR}/libspatialite.a

${LIBDIR}/libspatialite.a: ${LIBDIR}/libproj.a ${LIBDIR}/libgeos.a ${LIBDIR}/libsqlite3.a ${CURDIR}/spatialite
    cd spatialite && env \
    CXX=${CXX} \
    CC=${CC} \
    CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" \
    CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" \
    LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -liconv -lgeos -lgeos_c -lc++" ./configure --host=${HOST} --disable-freexl --prefix=${PREFIX} --with-geosconfig=${BINDIR}/geos-config --disable-shared && make clean install-strip


clean:
    rm -rf build geos proj spatialite sqlite3 include lib
```

@gagan-ios , @kristina-brooks - It seems Makefile within spatialite directory is getting generated automatically from above Makefile.I am not sure how I can control the lib ,include path to libxml2 dynamically.

**Edit2**
One more level of investigation shows ,library getting generated for i386 and x86_64 and failing for armv7,armv7s and arm64

> ${MAKE} arch ARCH=armv7 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
>       ${MAKE} arch ARCH=armv7s IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
>       ${MAKE} arch ARCH=arm64 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneOS HOST=arm-apple-darwin
>       ${MAKE} arch ARCH=i386 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator HOST=i386-apple-darwin
>       ${MAKE} arch ARCH=x86_64 IOS_PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator HOST=x86_64-apple-darwin

Comment: check for integration & add other linker flag as suggested in SDK's docs.

Answer (score 0):

A suitable libxml2 stub should be present in the iPhoneOS SDK, just adding `-lxml2` to linker flags should work. I'm guessing you've explicitly specified an absolute path to `libxml2.dylib` instead of letting the linker use the SDK relative path, so you're trying to link an ARM static library against an x86_64 version of libxml2 from your OS distribution.

Comment: I am trying to build from here https://github.com/gstf/libspatialite-ios , With your suggestion, I noticed that Makefile contains below entry LIBXML2_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lxml2.....perhaps I have to edit this to point  another location..

Comment: No luck editing the Makefile resulting in same error

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to find a workaround with the help of Makefile at [Compiling external C++ library for use with iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016612/compiling-external-c-library-for-use-with-ios-project)

The work around is an amalgamation of 2 different make files and involved below steps.

1.Use the Makefile partially to generate libraries for all platforms for dependencies (pros,geos,sqlite3) https://github.com/gstf/libspatialite-ios

2.Compiled libxml2 from source using the Makefile from [Compiling external C++ library for use with iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016612/compiling-external-c-library-for-use-with-ios-project)

3.Makefile from [Compiling external C++ library for use with iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016612/compiling-external-c-library-for-use-with-ios-project)  is used to generate spatialite libraries for all platforms

4.Use lipo from Step#1 Makefile to generate fat library

```
#!/bin/bash

PLATFORMPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
TOOLSPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="8.0"
pwd=`pwd`

findLatestSDKVersion()
{
    sdks=`ls $PLATFORMPATH/$1.platform/Developer/SDKs`
    arr=()
    for sdk in $sdks
    do
       arr[${#arr[@]}]=$sdk
    done

    # Last item will be the current SDK, since it is alpha ordered
    count=${#arr[@]}
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
       sdk=${arr[$count-1]:${#1}}
       num=`expr ${#sdk}-4`
       SDKVERSION=${sdk:0:$num}
    else
       SDKVERSION="8.0"
    fi
}

buildit()
{
    target=$1
    hosttarget=$1
    platform=$2

    if [[ $hosttarget == "x86_64" ]]; then
        hostarget="i386"
    elif [[ $hosttarget == "arm64" ]]; then
        hosttarget="arm"
    fi

    export CC="$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang)"
    export CPP="$CC -E"
    export CFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
    export AR=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar)
    export RANLIB=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ranlib)
    export CPPFLAGS="-arch ${target}  -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
    export LDFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk"

    mkdir -p $pwd/output/$target

     ./configure --prefix="$pwd/output/$target" --disable-shared --disable-sqlite --host=$hosttarget-apple-darwin

    make clean
    make
    make install
}

findLatestSDKVersion iPhoneOS

buildit armv7 iPhoneOS
buildit armv7s iPhoneOS
buildit arm64 iPhoneOS
buildit i386 iPhoneSimulator
buildit x86_64 iPhoneSimulator
```

Add these libraries to a new Xcode project and start using it.
Well here is my first success using this library

Include these libraries

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <spatialite/gaiageo.h>
#include <spatialite.h>
```

Use the below APIs to get the Spatialite version

```
spatialite_init(0);
printf("Spatialite version: %s\n", spatialite_version());
```

Output

```
Spatialite version: 4.3.0
```