# How to build and use C library in iOS project?

Tags: ios, c

I am new in iOS programming. I have an Android app that use c library. I want to create same iOS app and use same library. I search about it but most of results are for objective-c programming and there are various methods that I cannot choose from. I believe with new features I can do it much more simple in swift.
So my question is how should I create C library and use it in iOS project? Can I use cmake? Should I use Swift package manager like what said in first link below?

best result I found on internet:

1. https://medium.com/shopify-mobile/wrapping-a-c-library-in-swift-part-1-6dd240070cef
2. [Compiling external C++ library for use with iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016612/compiling-external-c-library-for-use-with-ios-project)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode can compile C code without additional settings. Just add your C files to your project and select a proper target.

One way to use C code from Swift is with a bridging header (another way is to use a *modulemap* file, it's more flexible and convenient but also a bit more complex to setup).

Here is an example on how to use C and Swift in the same project, you can use the same technique with your existing C code.

1. Create a new iOS project.
2. Add a new C file with a corresponding header (Xcode will prompt you).
   [image: C file]
3. Xcode should suggest to add a bridging header and create it automatically. If it doesn't happen you can create it manually and add it to your project's *Build Settings*.
   [image: Bridging header]
   [image: Build settings]
4. Add some code to your .c and .h files, for example:

   ```
    // example.h
    #include <stdio.h>
    int exampleMax(int num1, int num2);


    // example.c
    #include "example.h"

    int exampleMax(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result;
        if (num1 > num2)
            result = num1;
        else
            result = num2;
        return result; 
    }
   ```
5. Add your C header to the bridging file:

   ```
    // ModuleName-Bridging-Header.h
    #import "example.h"
   ```
6. Now you can call your C function from Swift:

   ```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let number1 = Int32(1)
            let number2 = Int32(5)
            let result = exampleMax(number1, number2)
            print("min = \(result)")
        }
    }
   ```

Auto-completion should recognize your C interface:

[image: Auto completion]

Comment: I do not want to copy all files whenever some changes happen in c code so I prefer to use library. Isn't using library a better approach?